# Base address of VDU memory of Intel HD Graphics to use it in C to display directly into the monitor

Tags: windows, dos

I would like to write directly into the VDU memory and print "string" in the display. I read in a book where we can achieve this by writing directly into the VDU memory based address 0xB8000000. But i dont know whether this address is the right address of display memory in my laptop. I can play and see, but still i was skeptical whether that would screw up something. Can someone help me how to know the base address. My laptop is Acer ASPIRE. I have Interl HD Graphics card.

Comment: How old is the book you have read ? Modern operating systems have memory protection mechanisms that forbid access to these zones. You're in for a lot of trouble dealing with these ancient techniques.

Comment: You need a time machine to take you back to the 1980s.

Answer (score 1):

This was valid in the old MS DOS times. The black/white video card had a base address of 0xb0000000, while the color video card (CGA) had 0xb8000000. When the VGA was introduced, 0xB8000000 was still correct in text mode but not in graphics mode; when windows started using protected mode and 32 bit (around 1995 with windows 95), all these addresses became invalid.

So you need to either use FreeDos to boot your laptop, or use an emulator like DOSEMU to get anything from writing to those addresses.

Comment: This takes me way back, but wasn't it `B000:0000` and `B800:0000`, i.e. segment addresses rather than linear addressing?

Comment: Yes it was. From the address bus viewpoint, the memory addresses were B0000 resp. B8000 beause of how the segment registers worked; from the programmers viewpoint, you still needed to tell your compiler to use the large/huge memory model, and initialize your pointer like `int *videoram=0xb0000000;`. int, not char, since every character on the screen had one byte for the ascii code and another for the attributes.

Comment: @abligh, segment addresses in the processor were converted to linear physical addresses on the bus. There are multiple segment address combinations that can refer to the same physical address. Edit: although surely the 32-bit addresses in this answer are wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom in real mode though (where that address comes from) it was a fixed 4 bit shift, so the real address would be `B0000` and `B8000` IIRC. Of course if you are thinking of using those fancy new fangled protected mode with segment descriptors and the like it could be anywhere.

Comment: The really weird thing was that B000:1000 was the same as B100:0000. Or, FFFF:0010 was the same as 0000:0000, which was used in copy protection schemes often, but broke on the 80286 that was able to address more than 1 MB, so the AT designers integrated a software controlled AND gate into the Mainboard to force the A16 memory line to 0. Omg, i fell like a grandpa talking about the war ...

Comment: (Actually Windows used protected mode and 32 bits starting with Windows/386 in 1988 but who's keeping score?)